# How do I create English-language list (name1, name2, AND name3) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, string

Quite possibly there could be a rails magic I've missed, but I'm guessing it will be in Ruby.

I have a model called Company which has_many Contacts.

Suppose Company has Contact 1, Contact 2, Contact 3, and Contact 4.

When I create a textblog for each Contact, I want to output the following (where Contact = Contact 1)

"Hi, Contact 1,
 I am also writing to Contact 2, Contact 3, and Contact 4."

So it needs to extract the Contact in the salutation and then list them, inserting "and" before the last Contact in the list.

**Edit**

I now have the following:

This is in contacts_controller.rb

```
  def full_name
   [self.first_name, self.last_name].compact.join(" ")
  end
```

in contact_letters_controllers.rb (contact_letters are the executed contacts with letters)

```
  def new

    @contact_letter = ContactLetter.new
    @contact_letter.contact_id = params[:contact]
    @contact_letter.letter_id = params[:letter]

    @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact])
    @company = Company.find(@contact.company_id)

    contacts = @company.contacts.collect(&:full_name)

    contacts.each do |contact|
       @colleagues = contacts.reject{ |c| c==@contact.full_name }
    end

    @letter = Letter.find(@contact_letter.letter_id)

    @letter.body.gsub!("{FirstName}", @contact.first_name)
    @letter.body.gsub!("{Company}", @contact.company_name) 
    @letter.body.gsub!("{Colleagues}", @colleagues.to_sentence)

    @contact_letter.body = @letter.body
    @contact_letter.status = "sent"

  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`to_sentence`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions.html#M002991) is what you're looking for.

You could try something like the following:

```
contacts = Company.contacts.collect(&:name)

contacts.each do |contact|
   other_contacts = contacts.reject{ |c| c==contact }
   p "Hi, #{contact}, I am also writing to #{other_contacts.to_sentence}"
end
```

I didn't test this code, so forgive me if this doesn't work.

**Edit**

This method will return the contact's full_name. If you also have a `middle_name` attribute, you can add on the array. This method will still work if any of the attributes is `nil`.

```
def full_name
   [self.first_name, self.last_name].compact.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: pretty close...one challenge.  The contacts have a :first_name and :last_name, how can I aggregate these into a single :full_name?

Comment: you can add a `full_name` method to your `Contact` model. see my edited answer...

Comment: Hi, thanks --- so where would I put the method?  I've edited to show what I've done...thanks.  This change creates an undefined method:

undefined method `full_name'

Comment: You must put the method on `Contact` model.